# Famous TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm having an issue will uploading a docx file with multer.

What i've declared :

**app.js multer config**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, __dirname + process.env.UPLOAD_DIR); // '/uploads'
  }
});
var uploadService = multer({
  storage: storage,
  // limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
  fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    if (ext !== '.docx') {
      return callback(res.end('Only docx are allowed'), null)
    }
    callback(null, true)
  }
});
app.post('/upload', uploadService.single('file'), uploadController.postFileUpload);
```

**upload.js**

```
exports.postFileUpload = (req, res, next) => {
  // Data receiver parameters
  var jsonData = '';
  var buffer = generateDoc(jsonData, req.file);
[...]
  res.status(200).end();
};


function generateDoc(data, file) {
  var doc = new Docxtemplater();
  var wordDocument = file;
  var filepath = wordDocument.path;
  console.log(filepath); // prints file path ex : D:\doc_tpl\uploads\0816cdb5c82d458ed930d0048b603d8a
  var content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(filepath), 'binary'); // throws error, wtf ?
 [...]
  return buffer;
}
```

Then i've got this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
>       at generateDoc (D:\doc_tpl\controllers\upload.js:17:31)

I can't use the var, and, as you can see, passing through another variable wont fix the problem..

I'm using Node@8.7 , "express": "^4.15.4", "multer": "^1.3.0". And my pug html body seems clean :

```
form#file-uploader.dropzone(method='post', action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data')
  .fallback
    input(name='file' type='file')
```

What's wrong on this code ?

Comment: Are the comments in your code correct, so it prints out the path to the console and then fails on the next line? That doesn't tally with the error message, which is trying to read a property called `path`, which suggests it's failing on the line `var filepath = wordDocument.path`. Try attaching a debugger, see https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: @skirtle Thanks, that's better with this debug tool. I can now clearly see that my request is being treaten twice. However, right now I can't find out exactly why, as my browser sends only one request. First time my file is present & treaten correctly. But, the second time, request.file is undefined, and there are no parameters.
Edit : Weird thing, the null request randomly appears before or after the right one.

Comment: My best guess is you've got a callback somewhere that you're invoking twice, maybe `next`. If you sprinkle `app.use(function(req, res, next){console.log('here');next()});` at various points between your middleware/routes (changing the log message each time) you should be able to establish where the request gets split in two.

Comment: @skirtle Well, I found a quite simple solution, which will partialy fix the problem. I haven't found any callbacks. So I made a `if(res.file) ...`, then it worked.